# Tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell, didselectrowatindexpath

I have UITableView and CustomCell also i use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to select row.

My problem is that cell is marked by clicking on it heavily to the left . How I click in the middle or on the right nothing happens . Anyone knows the solution ?

EDIT :

its my cell screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0dLu.png)

If I click in middle or right nothing happens but if i click on left imageView i call my function and cell is selected

Comment: To clarify, is the problem that when you tap middle or right nothing happens but works only you tap to the left? Also can you show us what you have got so far?

Comment: may be add buttons to the table cell if you want to customise your tap. put buttons on where you want to tap

Comment: please add an image so we can see, and also, if possible, a screen of storyboard cell editor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have details about the view hierarchy in your custom cell but I suspect the problem is the key responder.

I mean, I guess you have a button, view with tap gesture… something that capture your tap and doesn't allow to the tap reach the cell. Analyze your view hierarchy.

See the image:

[image: view hierarchy in your cell]

Could you give me more details about the view hierarchy please?

Comment: Do you have all the views with user interaction = YES?

Comment: Yes. I solved my problem. I changed my Cell for just UIView